# Mysterious Disappearing Bridge, or how can I get it back?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I had a bridge linked to a switch. The switch was pulled, and the switch was dismantled while pulled (and the linked bridge was retracted). I'd assumed that the bridge would extend or I'd be able to link it up to a new switch... am I out of luck? My mechanic keeps suspended the link job. Do I have to dissassemble the old retracted bridge and build it anew?

Comment: can your mechanic reach where the retracted bridge should be?

Comment: Yes. Really it's less a bridge, and more a 3x6 disappearing floor, but both sides are accessible.

Comment: Can you still 'q'uery the vanished bridge?

Comment: I can. I'd rather not disassemble it, and of course it's possible that it can't be disassembled, but I certainly can't build a new bridge there (lists as building present).
BTW, this game is on 40d, not the latest build.

Comment: You may not have a choice other than disassembling it, though. Is it suspended over something you'd rather not lose, or what? I don't understand why you'd rather not disassemble it.

Comment: The reason I'd rather not disassemble it, is because actually it's a half dozen bridges all w/ the same problem. Basically I accidentally connected an extra bridge to the lever and I thought it would be easier to rebuild the lever then the bridge... but I guess because I disassembled the lever whilst it was pulled I was wrong.

Comment: Hm. No way you can just revert to an older save, I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

once in an older version i was able to build a wall over where the bridge was/should be, and then order the wall removed, magicly at the same time the old bridge was removed, then i had to just build the bridge back :(

not a nice way to fix it, but might help you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with flood gates, since the gates disappear when you pull the lever. I rebuilt a lever in the same place and it magically worked, somehow. I was on 2010 though, not 40d, so it might not work for you. Worth a try though.